# Align in environment {align}

Tags: align

[image]

How can I right-align what's in red within an align environment? I try with flushright but not works.
thanks

Comment: Just put `&&` before these texts. E.g. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Einstein}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{align}
 x&\le y && \text{per \eqref{eq:Einstein}}\\
 &=NV&&\text{per \dots}\\
 &\le AB&& \text{per \eqref{eq:Einstein}}
\end{align}
\end{document}`. It is a bit cumbersome to type your equation, please post the code that generated the above output if this does not help.

Comment: Your solution works but, I need the equations in the center, and the text slightly aligned to the right

Comment: I'd suggest `{numcases}` for the whole thing (cases.sty).

Answer (score 1):

You can have equations centred and the text aligned on the right using a combination of `alignat` and `\rlap` (within certain limits):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}\lVert\rVert

\begin{document} 

\setcounter{section}{3}
\setcounter{equation}{23}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\noindent We have
\begin{alignat}{2}
\norm{\mathcal{G}}_{\alpha p} &\le N 
\norm{\mathcal{G}(u)}_{\mathcal{H}^{s, p}_{r}(a)}, &\quad& \rlap{\small por (3.16)}\\
&=N \norm{V(\cdot, u)}_p&&\rlap{\small por 
Teorema 3.1}\\
&\le 2^p C^p N\bigl(\norm{h}_p + 
\norm{u}^{\alpha}_{\alpha p} \bigr)&& \rlap{\small por (3.23)}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Zarko!